# Parsing inconsistent HTML with XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to gather information from a web page that has inconsistent HTML, for example:

```
<ul><li>Item #1</li></ul><ul><li>sub Item #1</li></ul>
```

and that's alright, I use the XPath expression

```
//div[@id="content"]/ul/li/text()
```

and it does the job (except that doesn't gather the information from sub Item #1.,

Also the HTML varies and this is other way:

```
 <dl><dd><ul><li>Item #1</li></ul></dd></dl><dl><dd><ul><li>sub Item #1</li></ul></dd></dl>
```

Well, I'm trying to gather Item #1 and sub Item #1. But with this inconsistent HTML I'm not able to find an XPath expression that will allow me to gather the information in any case, could you help me with this?

There will always be a list, the Item #1 and sub Item #1 always will be inside a `<ul><li>`

Comment: How are you getting the HTML? Can you give us a link to the source?

Comment: Yes @LegoStormtroopr I'm trying this two pages: http://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Los_Simpson and http://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Friends

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `descendant` axis (`//`) to select `ul/li/text()` no matter how deep it is nested within a consistent ancestor/parent. For example, assuming that ancestor/parent of `ul/li` is always a `div` having `id` equals `"content"` :

```
//div[@id="content"]//ul/li/text()
```